# Dockerfile testcontainers Can not connect to Ryuk

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, testcontainers

I try to dockerize my java spring application.

In my build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter'
implementation 'org.testcontainers:postgresql'
```

In my test file:

```
@SpringBootTest
class ApplicationTests {

@ClassRule
public static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:11.1")
    .withDatabaseName("integration-tests-db")
    .withUsername("sa")
    .withPassword("sa");

static class Initializer
    implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
        TestPropertyValues.of(
            "spring.datasource.url=" + postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
            "spring.datasource.username=" + postgreSQLContainer.getUsername(),
            "spring.datasource.password=" + postgreSQLContainer.getPassword()
        ).applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
    }
}
```

}

Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk16:jdk-16.0.2_7-alpine-slim
MAINTAINER myapplication

ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/myapplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

COPY ${JAR_FILE} myapplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/myapplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

then from terminal I run:

```
docker build --no-cache  --tag=myapplication:latest .

docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -p8080:8080 myapplication:latest
```

And after all I see an error:

> 2021-10-24 09:12:25.781  WARN [,,] 1 --- [containers-ryuk]
> o.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper  : Can not connect to Ryuk at
> 172.17.0.1:50582
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:669) ~[na:na]    at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
> ~[na:na]  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:645)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper.lambda$null$1(ResourceReaper.java:189)
> ~[testcontainers-1.16.0.jar!/:na]     at
> org.rnorth.ducttape.ratelimits.RateLimiter.doWhenReady(RateLimiter.java:27)
> ~[duct-tape-1.0.8.jar!/:na]   at
> org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper.lambda$start$2(ResourceReaper.java:185)
> ~[testcontainers-1.16.0.jar!/:na]     at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]

What am I doing wrong? Unfortunately, after two days of struggling, I have run out of ideas.

btw: I disabled Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing from Docker and didn't help.
I use macos.

Comment: Have you got a solution to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

add `-e TESTCONTAINERS_HOST_OVERRIDE=docker.for.mac.host.internal` after your run command

```
docker run -e TESTCONTAINERS_HOST_OVERRIDE=docker.for.mac.host.internal ...
```

Comment: it's `host.docker.internal` and for macos the only correct solution to fix this!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Testcontainers docs](https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/dind_patterns/) the `WORKDIR` should have the same absolute path as the OS launching point. Try to add these configs

```sh
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
           -p 8080:8080 \
           -v $PWD:$PWD \
           -w $PWD \
            myapplication:latest
```